# Add reference to dll in powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I created a dll in C# and would like to use it in PowerShell.

I know I can load the dll using:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("MyDll.dll")
```

But I don't want to use reflection.

Is there a simple way to do include my dll without reflection? Something like add reference to this dll?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0 the cmdlet `Add-Type` is designed for this, for example:

```
Add-Type -Path "$env:Xyz\bin\Npgsql.dll"
```

(it’s more likely that under the covers it calls the same `LoadFile` but this way is more PowerShell-ish)

Comment: This could also help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848741/can-i-write-a-class-using-powershell