# Is there any tool that can do c# code to powershell

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-cmdlet

I was wondering if there is an online tool that can convert c# code to powershell cmdlet code. I have following code that i need to have it powershell. I dont have visual studio to turn this into an exe or dll. any help or ideas would be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace CopyUsersBetweenGroupsInSharepointByRR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This tool will copy the users from one group to another group");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the URL of the site where your groups are available");
            String siteUrl = Console.ReadLine();
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the source group");
                    String sourceGroupName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the name of the destination group");
                    String destinationGroupName = Console.ReadLine();
                    SPGroup sourceGroup = web.Groups[sourceGroupName];
                    SPGroup destinationGroup = web.Groups[destinationGroupName];
                    SPUserCollection sourceUsers = sourceGroup.Users;
                    SPUserInfo[] sourceUserInfoArray = new SPUserInfo[sourceUsers.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < sourceUsers.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sourceUserInfoArray[i] = new SPUserInfo();
                        sourceUserInfoArray[i].LoginName = sourceUsers[i].LoginName;
                        sourceUserInfoArray[i].Name = sourceUsers[i].Name;
                    }
                    destinationGroup.Users.AddCollection(sourceUserInfoArray);
                    destinationGroup.Update();
                    web.Update();
                    Console.WriteLine("Operation Completed Successfully");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just download a trial of VS...

Comment: I don't think there is any C#-to-PowerShell compiler...

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio Express could help?

Comment: I was wondering what warranted for negative feedback on my post. I simply wanted to know if there is an alternate way to convert c# to powershell. we are under HEAVEY time crunch due to sudden merger. Sorry if I messed up the post.

Comment: it seems that the tool is called @Sharken :)

Comment: @torres I did not down vote, but since you asked, I thought you might benefit from a response. Generally, "translate my code" type posts are not judged to be good questions by the SO community. They often show little effort on the part of the asker, are too localized, and are difficult for others to learn from. I suspect your phrasing with "Is there a tool to do this translation" was seen as a superficial attempt to turn "translate my code" into a question.

Comment: Why is there so many downvotes? This question is all right.

Comment: Too many misguided souls on SO, tying to collect all their badges and stats...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Methods to convert C# code to a PowerShell Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143460/methods-to-convert-c-sharp-code-to-a-powershell-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way to do it is to write the PowerShell code yourself.
Below is how the code will look in PowerShell, i would say that most C# developers should be able to grasp the concepts of converting C# code to PowerShell in a very short time.

Functions can be a little odd at the beginning, since the usual PS syntax is

```
myFunction Parameter1 Parameter2
```

Also you really should install PowerShell 3.0 and use the Windows PowerShell ISE tool to develop the code.
Anyways it should not take you more than 1-2 hours to get your C# code running along in PowerShell.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(”Microsoft.SharePoint”) 
Write-Host "This tool will copy the users from one group to another group"
Write-Host "Please enter the URL of the site where your groups are available"
[string] $siteUrl = [Console]::ReadLine()

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl) 
try
{
  $web = $site.OpenWeb()
  Write-Host "Please enter the name of the source group"
  [string] $sourceGroupName = [Console]::ReadLine()
  Write-Host "Please enter the name of the destination group"
  [string] $destinationGroupName = [Console]::ReadLine()
  $sourceUsers = $web.Groups[$sourceGroupName]

  (and so on)
}
catch
{
  Write-Error ("Failed to copy sharepoint users." + $_)
}
```

Comment: you could also create your own new type. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848741/can-i-write-a-class-using-powershell

Answer (score 7):

It's comments like those above that are turning people away from SO in droves. The OP's question was unambiguous and displayed genuine need.

There are several ways to achieve this. Rewriting your entire C# code repository is not one of them.

As already discussed, as of PS 2 you are able to either run C# (or most any other language) inline, or refer to well-formed external file. I've had mixed success with this and I don't believe it's what the OP was really after.

If you genuinely want to convert code (particularly compiled assemblies) then a decompiler like Reflector is able to do this and - with the PowerShell addon - is also able to convert it on-the-fly.

http://blog.lekman.com/2011/10/converting-c-to-powershell.html

If you want your input and output to take place within the PS console then you'd still have to perform some obvious re-writes. But this method has proved incredibly useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is anything remotely like that, however Visual Studio is not required to compile c# code. You could compile an exe without VS. The compiler (csc.exe) and msbuild are included as part of framework. They are located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}`.

If you really want to call this from powershell, have a look at the `Add-Type` cmdlet. You provide it the source code and it will compile the source on the fly, then load the assembly into your session.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about online tools, but download the free Visual Studio Express & follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd878321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should have you creating a cmdlet in no time

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I don't think you can even get Visual Studio Express any more. But then this post is nearly 8 years old