# Cannot call exit() from a method within a custom object

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I'm trying to emulate classes using PS modules as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6848777/612462) answer. However, it doesn't seem possible to `exit` from within such an "instance method":

```
$sb =
{
    function bar
    {
        "bar"
    }

    function quux
    {
        exit
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Function bar,quux
}
$foo = New-Module $sb -AsCustomObject
$foo.bar()
$foo.quux()
```

results in

```
bar
Exception calling "quux" with "0" argument(s): "System error."
At line:17 char:1
+ $foo.quux()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodFlowControlException
```

1. Why does this happen in the first place and why is the exception so cryptic?
2. What is the canonical way of doing this correctly? I do want to exit and stop all further execution, not resume control flow. I also need to be able to return an exit code.

Comment: Hi, doesn't PS v5 support classes ?

Comment: @sodawillow It does, but this has to be portable so I can't rely on v5 features.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw an exception and use `trap` to catch it and exit the script:

```
trap{
    exit
}

$sb =
{
    function bar
    {
        "bar"
    }

    function quux
    {
        throw "Stopping execution"
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Function bar,quux
}
$foo = New-Module $sb -AsCustomObject
$foo.bar()
$foo.quux()
```

Comment: No, I want to stop all execution immediately.

Comment: This obviously throws an exception which doesn't allow me to exit "gracefully" (plus it produces output - the exception - which is a no-no), neither does it allow me to exit with a specific exit code. It doesn't really answer why my minimal example throws the exception it does in the first place either. Thanks for trying to help but this just doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: I didn't read your question carefully enough. However I may found a solution for your.

Comment: I don't know why but this just resumes control flow after calling `$foo.quux()` for me.

Comment: You probably have to set  `$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'`

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth, I know this is years later, but `trap{ exit }` should indeed cause overall execution to terminate, in response to the _statement_-terminating error `$foo.quux()` generates; it is only `$foo.quux()` _by itself_ that causes execution to continue by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen in the first place and why is the exception so cryptic?

The behavior you're seeing **appears to be a *bug*** (still present as of PowerShell 7.0; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12235)):

**Calling `exit`** from a ***script method* attached to a `[pscustomobject]` instance** - whether the script method is indirectly attached via [`New-Module -AsCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-module) or directly via
[`Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) - **unexpectedly fails** with the cryptic error you saw: instead of exiting, the error is emitted as a *statement*-terminating error (see below) and execution *continues* by default.

Methods defined on a **PowerShell 5+ [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)** are ***not* affected**.

> What is the canonical way of doing this correctly? I do want to exit and stop all further execution, not resume control flow. I also need to be able to return an exit code.

Typically, `exit` is called from the top-level scope of a *script* file, not from inside a function (whether or not inside a module).

Note that `exit` either immediately exits the *enclosing script*, or, if the function is called directly in an interactive session, *exists the whole session*.

If your `quux()` method is called from within a script, and you indeed want to exit the enclosing script instantly, the **only *direct* workaround in PowerShell 4-** is *not* to try to emulate a PowerShell class and to **define and call the `quux` function *directly***.

However, an ***indirect* workaround** is to add a minor tweak to the `throw` approach from [Martin Brandl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39702035/45375):

---

The solution is complicated by **PowerShell's inconsistent use of terminating errors**, which fall into two categories:

- ***statement*-terminating errors**, which (by default) terminate the executing statement only, and then *continue* execution.
- ***script*-terminating errors** (fatal errors), which terminate execution overall (a script and all its callers, and, in the case of a call to PowerShell's CLI, the PowerShell process as a whole).

This surprising distinction and PowerShell's surprisingly complex error handling in general are described in [this GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583).

A **script method** attached to a `[pscustomobject]` instance, as used in your dynamic-module approach, is **only capable of generating a *statement*-terminating error**, not a script-terminating one.

Again, **PowerShell 5+ `class` methods** behave differently: they **create *script*-terminating errors**.

**To achieve *overall* termination while also reporting an exit code**<sup>[1]</sup>, you additionally need to do the following in the *caller*'s scope:

- catch / trap the statement-terminating error.
- issue an `exit $n` statement in response (which in the context of the script scope will succeed), where `$n` is the desired exit code.

You have two options:

- Add a [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap) statement to the caller's scope, which fires for both statement- and script-terminating errors and calls `exit $n`, where `$n` is the desired exit code.

  - To do so, the only tweak to Martin's answer is to replace `trap { exit }` with, say,
    `trap { exit 1 }` to report exit code `1`.
  - Communicating the specific exit code from the `throw`ing function takes extra work - see below.
  - Note that `trap` is rarely used, but it enables a straightforward solution in your case.
- Alternatively, use a [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement around the method call or a group of statements that could throw an error, and call `exit` in the `catch` handler:
  `try { $foo.quux() } catch { exit 1 }`

---

#### Workaround that sets a specific exit code:

```
# Create a custom object with methods,
# via a dynamic module.
$foo = New-Module -AsCustomObject {
    function bar
    {
        "bar"
    }
    function quux
    {
      # Throw a statement-terminating error with the desired exit code,
      # to be handled by the `trap` statement in the caller's scope.      
      throw 5
    }
}

# Set up the trap statement for any terminating error.
# Note: Normally, you'd place the `trap` statement at the
#       beginning of the script.
trap {
  # Get the exit code from the most recent error or default to 1.
  # Note: $_ is a *wrapper* error record arund the original error record
  #       created with `throw`; however, the wrapper's .ToString() representation
  #       is the (string representation of) the original object thrown.
  if (-not ($exitCode = $_.ToString() -as [int])) { $exitCode = 1 }
  exit $exitCode
}

$foo.bar()
$foo.quux() # This triggers the trap.

# Getting here means that the script will exit with exit code 0
# (assuming no other terminating error occurs in the remaining code).
```

---

<sup>[1] If a script *automatically* terminates due to a *script*-terminating error, as a `class`-based solution would generate, its exit code is *invariably* reported as `1` (and the error message prints), but only *if the script was called via PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell.exe)* (`powershell -file ...` or `powershell -commmand ...`); by contrast,  inside an *interactive* PowerShell session `$LASTEXITCODE` is *not* set in this case (but the error message prints).

Therefore, even if a PS 5+ solution is an option, you may still want to trap the script-terminating error and explicitly translate it into an `exit` call with a specific exit code, as shown next.</sup>