# Reference .Net .dll from powershell script

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget, powershell-3.0

Could you please help me in referencing .Net .dll from powershell script? I'm using powershell ISE to write/debug script. I've some .net code which is referencing Nuget package in it and I want to embedded that code in powershell script.

It works well if I do copy required .dlls in C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 and script's root(C:\TestProjects\UpdateLocalNugetRepository) path. I don't want to do that beacuse in production we can not copy .dlls to system32 folder.I know that I'm doing something wrong. Could you please help?
Below is my powershell script -

```js
$path = "C:\TestProjects\UpdateLocalNugetRepository"

$Assem =@(
        "$path\NuGet.Configuration.dll",
        "$path\System.Core.dll",
        "$path\System.dll"
         ) 

         
$Source = @” 
using NuGet.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NuGetPSTest
{
    public class Utility
    {
  public static async Task<bool> MyMethod(string packageName, string p1, string p2)
        {
         //Here I use above mentioned .dll(Nuget.Configuration).
 }
    }

    
}

“@ 

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  



$result = [NuGetPSTest.Utility]::MyMethod(param1,param2,param3).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
$result
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add reference to dll in powershell 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360867/add-reference-to-dll-in-powershell-2-0)

Comment: I went through provided link, but it's slightly different. .Net packages are accessible to powershell but the nuget .dll is not accessible if I don't have on both location. I want to keep this .dll in root folder only and not in sys32.

Comment: This link might be of use to you: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/11/use-powershell-to-work-with-the-net-framework-classes/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Add-Type` snippet to load DLL's:

```
Add-Type -Path "$path\NuGet.Configuration.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\System.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\System.dll"
```

.Net DLL's can be added like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ServiceProcess
```

Check: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/11/11/use-powershell-to-work-with-the-net-framework-classes/

Comment: Sure..Let me give it a try.

Comment: You might want to use some environment variables to solve paths: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Comment: It's giving me below error -
The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the 
namespace 'NuGet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can be a host of things... this is a more generic error.

Comment: Only issue, I want to fix is that I don't want to copy .dlls to system32(C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0) folder.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for issue, need to do Add-Type before referring in assemblies to register another type. Below is my updated code.

```js
$path = "C:\TestProjects\UpdateLocalNugetRepository"

Add-Type -Path "$path\NuGet.Configuration.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\System.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$path\System.dll"

$Assem =@(
        "$path\NuGet.Configuration.dll",
        "$path\System.Core.dll",
        "$path\System.dll"
         ) 

         
$Source = @” 
using NuGet.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NuGetPSTest
{
    public class Utility
    {
  public static async Task<bool> MyMethod(string packageName, string p1, string p2)
        {
         //Here I use above mentioned .dll(Nuget.Configuration).
 }
    }

    
}

“@ 

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp  



$result = [NuGetPSTest.Utility]::MyMethod(param1,param2,param3).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
$result
```