# Running C# code with referenced DLL in PowerShell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

I know how to run C# code in PowerShell.
But in my `C#` code I want to use a referenced DLL (specifically [NtApiDotNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NtApiDotNet/)).
I installed it with NuGet in Visual Studio and it works fine because the referenced DLL is referenced by Visual Studio.
When I use the code inside PowerShell I don't see an option to reference the `C#` code to this DLL.
I tried to load the DLL with `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("c:\path\file.dll") | Out-Null` but it need to be loaded inside the `C#` code and therefore it doesn't help me.

I also tried to load it like that:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\NtApiDotNet.dll"
```

But it didn't work.

This is the powershell code:

```
$code = @"
using System;
using NtApiDotNet;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            NtSection section = null;
            Console.WriteLine("C# code from PowerShell");
        }
    }
}
"@

$location = [PsObject].Assembly.Location
$compileParams = New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
$assemblyRange = @("System.dll", $location)
$compileParams.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange($assemblyRange)
$compileParams.GenerateInMemory = $True
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -CompilerParameters $compileParams -passthru | Out-Null
[ConsoleApplication2.Program]::Main()
```

Because I don't reference the DLL I am getting the following error:

```
Add-Type : c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\s1fssauz.0.cs(2) : The type or namespace name 'NtApiDotNet' could not
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\s1fssauz.0.cs(1) : using System;
c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\s1fssauz.0.cs(2) : >>> using NtApiDotNet;
c:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\s1fssauz.0.cs(3) :
At line:24 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -CompilerParameters $compileParams -pa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Power...peCompilerError:AddTypeCompilerError) [Add-Type], Except
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
At line:24 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -CompilerParameters $compileParams -pa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Unable to find type [ConsoleApplication2.Program].
At line:25 char:1
+ [ConsoleApplication2.Program]::Main()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ConsoleApplication2.Program:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
```

How can I reference the DLL so I would be able to use the referenced DLL `NtApiDotNet` ?

Issue similar to mine can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827064/reference-net-dll-from-powershell-script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add the DLL to `ReferencedAssemblies`.
This is the fixed line:

```
$assemblyRange = @("System.dll", $location, "C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\NtApiDotNet.dll")
```

I used the `NtApiDotNet.dll` from the [releases](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/releases).
When I compiled it according to the readme file:

```
dotnet build NtApiDotNet\NtApiDotNet.Core.csproj -c Release
```

The DLL didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem as well, but fortunately I solved it. To address it, you need to install NtObjectManager module by using 
`Install-Module "NtObjectManager" -Scope CurrentUser`. 
If this not work, make sure you have import NtObjectManager.